# Minimizing the full adder - where did this XOR come from?

Tags: binary-arithmetic, xor

When minimizing the full adder, I don't understand why $A(\bar{B}\bar{C} + BC)$ reduces to $A\overline{(B\oplus{C})}.$

$(\bar{B}\bar{C} + BC)\to (B\oplus{C})$ is partially decipherable, but why is $(B\oplus{C})$ inverted to $\overline{(B\oplus{C})}?$

---

Full adder simplification:

$
\bar{A}\bar{B}C + \bar{A}B\bar{C} + A\bar{B}\bar{C} + ABC \\
= \bar{A}(\bar{B}C + B\bar{C}) + A(\bar{B}\bar{C} + BC) \\
= \bar{A}(B\oplus{C}) + A(\overline{B\oplus{C}}) \\
= A\oplus{(B\oplus{C})}
$

---

#### Could you help me out?

PS: I hope that this is the correct subforum of StackExchange to ask this (perhaps *Electrical Engineering* is the proper venue). I couldn't find appropriate tags on *either* site.

Comment: Does $\overline{\vee}$ mean the exclusive-or symbol?

Comment: Yes, it's XOR. I think that I may have chosen the wrong symbol, remedying now.

Comment: Yep, the wiki article says $\veebar$ to be a symbol, although I think $\oplus$ should be the most commonly used.

Comment: There. I changed $\veebar$ to $\oplus$

Comment: This may be a typo, but $(\bar{B}\bar{C} + BC)$ is not converted to $(B\oplus{C})$. Rather, $(\bar{B}C + B\bar{C})$ is converted.

Comment: It's my faulty reasoning in deciphering the equation, to show effort and mitigate the risk of hapless, furious onslaughts of downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint 1: Intuitively, $\oplus$ implies exactly one of the two inputs is $1$ ($B$ and $C$ here). Whereas, $(\bar{B}\bar{C} + BC)$ implies *both* inputs are $0$ or both are $1$.

Hint 2: Start from $\overline{(B \oplus C)}$, expand it, use [De'Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), simplify and you should reach $(\bar{B}\bar{C} + BC)$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'd upvote but I don't have the prerequisite rep points.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the truth table for $(\overline{B}\overline{C}+BC)$. It has 1's exactly when $B$ and $C$ get the same value, which is exactly when $(B\oplus C)$ gets 0, hence, $\overline{B\oplus C}$ is equivalent to $(\overline{B}\overline{C}+BC)$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll upvote when I have the prerequisite rep points.